# Mounting Windows Share from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, server-message-block

I've a windows shared folder which I can access by typing \share\files\ in "run" or address tab of windows file explorer.

I need to use that in Ubuntu. So I added

```
\\share\files\ /mnt/share/ cifs  guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

in `/etc/fstab`. And then issued `mount -a`. I got directory not resolvable error `mount error: could not resolve address for share: Unknown error`.

I tried adding

```
//share/files/ /mnt/share/ cifs  guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

in `/etc/fstab` and issuing `mount -a` command and got same error.

I used `id -u` and got 0, used that in `uid=0`.

I could ping the relevant IP.

**Edit:**
I used IP and got this output while trying to mount

```
Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Comment: You write you can ping the IP but seem to use name instead of an IP in your `/etc/fstab`. Have you checked that the name you use in the `/etc/fstab` resolves correctly to an IP address? PS: No need to apologize for being new here, we all have been new here once.

Comment: I recommend getting shares to mount using the "mount" or "mount.cifs" command before mucking around with fstab. eg: "mount.cifs //share/files/ /mnt/share/ --verbose -o guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8"

Comment: I updated the question a bit, can you guys please check?

Comment: Look in /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log for any other messages related to CIFS or authentication/protocol negotiation around the time the error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is indicating that it cannot connect to the Windows computer to access the share.  What seems to be happening is you're not setting the computer name correctly, the computer you're trying to access doesn't respond to **[mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)**, or you're not defining the first field (the CIFS source) properly.

The syntax for adding a cifs share in /etc/fstab should look something like one of these:

```
//computername/sharename/  /mnt/share  cifs  guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8 0 0
//10.10.10.100/sharename/  /mnt/share  cifs  guest,uid=0,iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

The structure for the first field is `//<hostname or ip>/<the name of the share>/`.

If you cannot contact the Windows computer using its name you can try using its IP address.

Comment: I used IP instead of path and got the following error message
`Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)`

Any idea?

Comment: Either the share doesn't permit guest access, the share name isn't correct, it's another configuration issue, or there's a bug with the samba software.  Verify the share on the windows computer permits guest access.  Additionally verify you have the most recent version of smbclient installed on your Ubuntu box.  Then update your initial question with your current configuration plus any errors from `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` that are related to samba/cifs.